# How to add an event to browser 'save file' dialog in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, browser, dialog, save

I have the following code:

```
 <input type="button" onclick="if(confirm('you wanna download?')){                                                                                                                            
 document.getElementById('formId').action = '../export_csv.php';                                                                                                                                                       
 document.getElementById('formId').submit();
 this.disabled = true; }"   />
```

If i Click OK the browser 'save file' dialog shows up on the screen. And i want to add an alert when the users press YES on that dialog. 
   Does anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to open save dialog box.

```
javascript:document.execCommand('SaveAs','1','fileName.txt')"
```

Comment: This only works on IE and I want to add a .php callback function when the users click on the OK browser's save File dialog.